# How establish connection between React JS and Apache Kafka in Spring Boot?

Tags: reactjs, apache-kafka

I have a question like in topic. How establish connection between React JS and Apache Kafka in Spring Boot ?

I don't know how connect to Apache Kafka and subscribe topic from React JS front-end.

Can I use this one ? Something like example below:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9092");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading [How to stream Kafka messages to Internet-facing clients over WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/topic/websockets-kafka) as that covers off most of what you need to know. Once have you a data stream to your browser, then plugging it into React JS (or perhaps Redux) should be straightforward.